# правильная оптимизация mysql

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, у меня вопрос
допустим есть таблица пользователей, где соответственно есть user (имя пользователя) , во время выборки новостей из бд, нужно  так же выводить имя автора, так вот у меня вопрос, лучше и оптимизированней при каждом выводе новостей, выбирать имя пользователя из таблицы user (проверяя совпадения поля author_id у новости, с id пользователем) и выводить соответственно имя пользователя, или сразу же при добавлении новости создать поле author и в него вносить имя пользователя, и выбирать это имя в новости уже вместе со всем остальным?

Так же аналогичная ситуация для комментов, правильнее создать поле comments у новости и при каждом комментировании обновлять число на 1 и выводить его, или же выводить SELECT COUNT ID FROM COMMENTS (тоесть выбирать количество записей в таблице комментариев)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с автором и новостью в большинстве случаев Вам просто нужно использовать JOIN и не хранить имя 2 раза. Повторное хранение имени приводит к денормализации  данных ([нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)) что не очень правильно при использовании реляционных СУБД как MySQL. Денормализации  данных иногда используется, но это сложная тема. Ознакомить можно [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/64524/%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82) или [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/latera/blog/281262/).

Случай с количество комментов же скорее оптимизация: если нет больной нагрузки и все работает нормально, то вариант с `SELECT` вполне допустим, если скорость работы уже критична то вариант с полем `comments` будет лучше.

Comment: Насчёт плевков в сторону денормализации возражений нет. Но при чём тут `JSON`?

Comment: @Akina JOIN, a не JSON. Я про это http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html

Comment: Мда, походу я не проснулся, пардон.